# Eclipse - How to set multiple viewers as selection providers from the same page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using a FormEditor with a page in an Eclipse application.
I have two treeviewers in the same page.
I want to update the property sheet view based on selection on the treeviewers.

I am currently able to set the selection provider for one tree as follows

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer1);
```

But I want to set both the treeviewers as selection providers.

I am totally new to this.
I want to know whether such kind of a setup is possible to do. If yes, how to do?
Please let me know if anyone knows how to do it.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one selection provider for the editor site, but it does not have to be the tree viewer. So you could write your own implementation of `ISelectionProvider` which uses the selections in the two trees.